Is there a way to prevent AG grid from hiding the loading spinner?
I'm using AG Grid in Angular and I have a loading spinner that I want to show and hide based on an observable, but it seems like AG Grid is hiding the spinner when the rowData is populated. Is there a way to make AG Grid ignore the rowData and only hide the spinner when I want it to be hidden?

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

As far as I could see, new spinner API (with ag grid v32+) grants you better control over spinner. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/overlays/#loading-overlay
I have used AgGrid since v25, so I've created custom spinner logic and separate component for all loading actions.

If you have access to grid Api you can use,
this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay()

// or 

this.gridApi.hideoverlay()

If you want to know more about overlays in ag grid
you can find the the information here Ag Grid Overlays
Hope this helps!

Thanks, but the problem is AG Grid hides the overlay on its own without me using hideOverlay(). I’m wondering if I can prevent AG Grid from doing that so that I can fully control showing/hiding the overlay myself.

this could help             this.gridOptions.overlayLoadingTemplate = <span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">${errMsg}</span>;
